# regex to exclude numerals from alphabets

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match all alphabet lists in a document.This is how they appear (on a new line) :

`(a)
(b)
(c)
(d)
..
..
(z)
(aa)
(bb)
..
(zz)`

This is the regex I am using for this `^ ?[\(]?([a-z])[\)]`

The challenge however is with roman numerals. I want to seperately identify roman numerals and I don't want to match them if they are part of this alphabet list. So for instance, alphabets and numerals will clash (under 50)  on `(i), (v), (x) and (c)`.

How do I write a regex to address this?

**EDIT**

Let me simplify the question.This is the sequence -

`(a)
(b)
(c)
(d)
(i)
(ii)
(iii)
(iv)
(v)
(e)`

From above, I want to match `(a) (b) (c) (d) (e)` not the numerals. 
The numerals are ALWAYS going to start at i. They can go max up to 50 in numerals. The regex also has to take care of matching `(a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f) (g) (h) (i) (j)` because i here is not numeral.

Comment: so, in short, I want to match alphabets, but not numerals that appear within the alphabets. So, say `(a) (b) (i) (ii) (c)`,  should exclude the `(i)` and `(ii)` between a b c.

Comment: Do you consider string `mix` to contain Roman number `X` ?

Comment: @MaxZoom No, mix is it not Roman. I am only considering characters in round brackets starting on new line.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Regex for not matching roman numerals in brackets, in new lines, which occour in sequence among alphabet list. It should work up to roman 50 (L).

```
\((?![ivxl]+)[a-z]+\)|(?<!xlix\)\n)\(l\)|(?<![ivxl]\)\n)\((?=[ivxl]+).+\)(?!\n\([ivxl]+\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aP6uE7/4)

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

If you don't want to match only full roman numeral, try with this:

```
\((?!\b([mdclx]+)?(i((ii?)|v|X)?|x|v(ii?i?)?)\b|[mdclx]+\b)[a-z]+\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fG1cV5/5)

which is:

- `\(` - opening bracket,
- `(?!\b([mdclx]+)?(i((ii?)|v|X)?|x|v(ii?i?)?)\b|[mdclx]+\b)` -
  negative look ahead to exclude varius versions of roman numerals, but
  enclosed by word boudaries `\b` so a whole word need to match for roman numeral,
- `[a-z]+\)` - one or more letters followed by closing bracket,

it seems my regex will probably sometimes match wrong, the proper regex seems to be (modified version from 
Regular Expressions Cookbook by Steven Levithan and Jan Goyvaerts):

```
\((?!\b([MDCLXVI])M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})\b)[a-z]+\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fG1cV5/8)

Result on these input is same, but it will differ in details

Comment: I think your regex is adding further complexity. The context is actually simpler. The idea is that if there are numerals, not any numerals, but a sequence of them starting from i and then ii and so on, then you ignore them and match the rest, but if it (i) as in i after h, then you select it. Something like this https://regex101.com/r/fG1cV5/7 but it needs to be improved.

Comment: @Jay I dont understand, in your question you said that you want to catch I,V,X,C, before 50 (what do you mean before 50? what with L,M and D?), now that numbers shluld be in sequence. Please provide more accurate details in question, without it it hard to find solution

Comment: @Jay I updated answer, it works with your new input, it is under **EDIT**, it works with L, as L is roman 50

Comment: @m.cekiera Your regex also matches `iiiii` string which is not a Roman number.

Comment: @MaxZoom thenks for comment, indeed it will match `(iiiii)` but only if it is after another 'roman' number, and to be honest, I don't want to waste more time on question, where conditions change becase OP don't want to spend too much time to post decent one, so it is my last shot